# How to connect Kafka with Camel Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-camel

What options do I have for connecting Kafka with Spring Boot Camel?

I'm running ActiveMQ Artemis and Camel to make JMS/MQTT and REST routes to/from clients.
I would like to add Kafka to that duo to stream/exchange data (video+audio, files/text).

So far I downloaded Kafka Confluent Platform (free trial) and I'm testing what they offer. In Confluent Platform I see it is possible to add connectors as a "plugins". I assume that way I can add Camel connector but that seems bad solution to me because I would like to play with the routes and see what is under the hood and here I don't see that is possible, or am I wrong?

Other option I'm thinking of, is to download Apache Kafka, Zookeeper, add Kafka Spring Boot dependency to Camel `pom.xml` and then make Camel routes like in samples [here](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html#_consumer_headers). Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Kafka-Broker**

If you want to play around, I recommend to **install Kafka** (it also brings Zookeeper) **on your development machine**. It is easiest to use a **package manager** for your operating system. For example if you work on Windows, you can install [Scoop](https://scoop.sh/).

Then you can install the current version of plain Kafka (not confluent platform) with a one-liner:

```
scoop install kafka
```

After installation you can **start first zookeeper, then kafka** with the provided bat/sh scripts in the bin folder.

**Camel**

In your Camel project (no matter if Spring Boot or not) you only need to add [camel-kafka](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html) to your dependencies.

The **route endpoint URI** for a Kafka broker running on your local machine is

```
kafka:[topic-name]?brokers=localhost:9092
```

You can use such URIs for consumer (`from("kafka:...")`) or producer (`.to("kafka:...")`)

Comment: OK, I see. If talking about Linux I assume [this](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) quickstart guide is good starting point for non Confluent installation of Kafka.

Comment: For now I tested Confluent Platform ([Docker](https://docs.confluent.io/current/quickstart/ce-docker-quickstart.html)) and noticed it is very RAM greedy. Connecting it with Camel was easy. I added [dependency](https://camel.apache.org/camel-spring-boot/latest/kafka-starter.html) to `pom.xml` and simple Camel routes to test sending from/to Kafka in java.

Comment: Quickstart für Linux looks good. Excelllent, happy journey!